# How do I turn a tag list into a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Could you please tell me how to turn a page with a list of all tags into a component that would be displayed on all pages? In this case, when you click on each tag, the page redraws and displays a list of posts with a specific tag.

In the current version of the site, the page with all tags, the tag page and the page with all posts are 3 different pages.

The clearest example of how I want to end up doing this is the https://colorlibhub.com/sparkling/ site (a free theme for Wordpress). There's a block with categories on the side, click on the one you want - the page displays the posts of that category.

gatsby-node.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const _ = require('lodash');

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/post.js');
  const tagTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/tags.js');

  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      postsRemark: allMdx(sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }, limit: 2000) {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
            frontmatter {
              tags
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
      tagsGroup: allMdx(limit: 2000) {
        group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
          fieldValue
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  // handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`);
    return;
  }

  const posts = result.data.postsRemark.edges;

  // Create post detail pages
  posts.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.frontmatter.url,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: { url: node.frontmatter.url },
    });
  });

  // Extract tag data from query
  const tags = result.data.tagsGroup.group;

  // Make tag pages
  tags.forEach((tag) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/tags/${_.kebabCase(tag.fieldValue)}/`,
      component: tagTemplate,
      context: {
        tag: tag.fieldValue,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

single tag page

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby';

import Header from '../components/header';
import Footer from '../components/footer';

import * as styles from './tags.module.scss';

const Tags = ({ pageContext, data }) => {
  const { tag } = pageContext;
  const { edges, totalCount } = data.allMdx;
  const tagHeader = `${totalCount} ${totalCount === 1 ? 'запись' : 'записи'} tagged with "${tag}"`;

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main className={`${styles.container} ${styles.page}`}>
        <h1>{tagHeader}</h1>
        <ul>
          {edges.map(({ node }) => {
            const { slug } = node;
            const { title, url } = node.frontmatter;
            return (
              <li key={slug}>
                <Link to={`/${url}`}>{title}</Link>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <Link to="/tags" className={styles.button}>
          All tags
        </Link>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

Tags.propTypes = {
  pageContext: PropTypes.shape({
    tag: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allMdx: PropTypes.shape({
      totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      edges: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          node: PropTypes.shape({
            frontmatter: PropTypes.shape({
              title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
            fields: PropTypes.shape({
              slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
          }),
        }).isRequired,
      ),
    }),
  }),
};

export default Tags;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query ($tag: String) {
    allMdx(
      limit: 2000
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { tags: { in: [$tag] } } }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          slug
          frontmatter {
            title
            url
          }
        }
      }
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          title
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

all tags page

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import kebabCase from 'lodash/kebabCase';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby';

import Header from '../../components/header';
import Footer from '../../components/footer';

import * as styles from './tags.module.scss';

const TagsPage = ({
  data: {
    allMdx: { group },
    site: {
      siteMetadata: { title },
    },
  },
}) => (
  <>
    <Helmet title={title} />
    <Header />
    <main className={`${styles.container} ${styles.page}`}>
      <h1>Tags</h1>
      <ul>
        {group.map((tag) => (
          <li key={tag.fieldValue}>
            <Link to={`/tags/${kebabCase(tag.fieldValue)}/`}>
              {tag.fieldValue} ({tag.totalCount})
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </main>
    <Footer />
  </>
);

TagsPage.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allMdx: PropTypes.shape({
      group: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          fieldValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
          totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        }).isRequired,
      ),
    }),
    site: PropTypes.shape({
      siteMetadata: PropTypes.shape({
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      }),
    }),
  }),
};

export default TagsPage;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMdx(limit: 2000) {
      group(field: frontmatter___tags) {
        fieldValue
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

blog page (list of all posts)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby';

import Layout from '../../components/layout';
import Seo from '../../components/seo';
import Card from '../../components/Card';

import * as blog from '../../components/blog.module.scss';

function BlogPage({ data }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Seo title="Статьи" />
      <main className={`${blog.container} ${blog.blog}`}>
        {data.allMdx.nodes.map((post) => (
          <Card
            key={post.id}
            category={post.frontmatter.tags.map((tag) => {
              return (
                <Link key={post.id} to={`/tags/${tag}`} className={blog.categoryLink}>
                  {tag}
                </Link>
              );
            })}
            title={post.frontmatter.title}
            description={post.frontmatter.description}
            link={`/${post.frontmatter.url}`}
          />
        ))}
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const PostsQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          title
          description
          date(formatString: "DD.MM.YYYY")
          tags
          url
        }
        id
        body
        slug
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default BlogPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) (like the one in `TagsPage`) only works in pages (or in top-level components) you can't just copy and paste your query into a component because it won't be a page anymore.

Your only chance given the scenario is to use a [static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/) to get all tags and display them into your component. There's a limitation using static queries: they don't accept dynamic parameters, since the `TagsPage` query is not using any filters (as `$tag` in `Tags` is) it won't be a problem.

Something like this should work:

```
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export default function YourComponent() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            title
            description
            date(formatString: "DD.MM.YYYY")
            tags
            url
          }
          id
          body
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  console.log("your tags are:", data);
  return <div> your loop here</div>;
}
```

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the static query. Thank you!

Yes, that's just what we need. Still need to solve the problem with the loop, which outputs the same tags several times. And if there's more than one tag in an entry, everything starts duplicating on the page :D

Unfortunately I can't give you a plus on your answer, not enough reputation :(

Comment: I guess it's because tags relationship with posts is one-to-many hence you are fetching several instances of the same tags. Once fetched, flatten the array and use a `new Set` to remove duplicates, then you can easily loop though them

Comment: Thank you! Gone to try it out)

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you again, because the static query helped to solve the problem. I had to rebuild half of the site, but it's working as it should.)